# "Creating precompiled collator because collator is out of date"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertview

I am trying to "self-destruct" a view controller by doing `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.

Before I do this, I also present an `UIAlertView`.

The first time I do this, I get a console-error that says:
`WARNING! Creating precompiled collator because collator is out of date. This is expensive!`

What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get that error at runtime or during the build? It sounds like a build error.

Comment: Hi Emil, The same happened to me today and my observation is that this is not an error just warning and it happen only when I use iOS 4.2.1 and when UIAlertView is popping up in navigation controller. It is just saying that it is expensive to use it like this, but in my case is everything working fine and even I have the same code already in app store so it seems to me OK.

Comment: Same warning here, not sure why.

Comment: I think that this error comes when you are building your iphone app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was simply due to a framework-error in the iOS 4.2.1 beta. I'm not getting this error anymore.